# iOS - Uploading image by HTTP POST

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, uiimage

**GOAL**: I would like to upload an image (*UIImage*) to server by HTTP POST method.

**PROBLEM**: I get a response "**You did not select a file to upload.**" (status = 200)

**HINT**: Here is a java code from Android application that works:

```
public static String sendImage(String url, String username, String password, String filePath) {
    try {
        File file = new File(filePath);
        int fileSize = (int) (file.length() / 1024);
        if (fileSize < 2048 && fileSize > 0) {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope(HOST, 80);
            UsernamePasswordCredentials usernamePasswordCredentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
            ((AbstractHttpClient) httpClient).getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(authScope, usernamePasswordCredentials);
            BasicHttpContext localHttpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            BasicScheme basicScheme = new BasicScheme();
            localHttpContext.setAttribute("preemptive-auth", basicScheme);

            HttpHost targetHttpHost = new HttpHost(HOST, 80, "http");
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setHeader("enctype", "multipart/form-data");

            MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            multipartEntity.addPart("userfile", new FileBody(file));
            httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(targetHttpHost, httpPost, localHttpContext);

            int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            String reason = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

            Log.d(TAG, "Status code: " + statusCode + " " + reason + "\n" + EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()));
            return "Status code: " + statusCode + " " + reason;
        } else {
            return "Please select image smaller than 200 kB";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

**MY CODE**:

```
+ (void)uploadPhotoToUserWithID:(int)userID photo:(UIImage *)photo
{
    // Convert UIImage to JPEG
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo, 0.5);

    // Create request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://XXX:XXX@example.com/upload/id/89"]];

    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:30];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"unique-consistent-string";

    // Post body
    NSMutableData *body = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    // Add image data
    if (imageData)
    {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=%@; filename=\"imageName.jpg\"\r\n", @"\"userfile\""] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:imageData];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // Setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    // Set Content-Type in HTTP header
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"enctype"];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", body.length];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
    {
        if(data.length > 0)
        {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
            NSLog(@"%i", httpResponse.statusCode);
        }
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Upload Image using below code..

```
   -(void)uploadPhotoToUserWithID:(int)userid photo:(UIImage *)loginpic
    {

            NSString *urlstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://XXX:XXX@example.com/upload/id/89"];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

             NSString *boundary = @"----WebKitFormBoundarycC4YiaUFwM44F6rT";
            NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
            [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

             NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];


              NSData *imageData;

                imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(loginpic, 0.2f);


            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            if(appDelegate.isPhototaken)
            {
                [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profilepic.jpeg\"; filename=\"picture.jpeg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                // We now need to tell the receiver what content type we have
                // In my case it's a png image. If you have a jpg, set it to 'image/jpg'
                [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            }
            else
            {
                [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profilepic.png\"; filename=\"picture.png\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

                // We now need to tell the receiver what content type we have
                // In my case it's a png image. If you have a jpg, set it to 'image/jpg'
                [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            }


            // Now we append the actual image data
            [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];

            // and again the delimiting boundary
            [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

            NSDictionary *dict;

            NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:NULL];
            [body appendData:jsonData];

            [request setHTTPBody:body];


            urlconnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

        }
        - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
    {
        respData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

        NSLog(@"@@@@@@@@@Data is:%@",response);
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
    {
        [respData appendData:data];
    }

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {

        NSError *errInfo;

        NSDictionary *mainDict= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:respData options:kNilOptions error:&errInfo];

        NSLog(@"maindictionary is %@",mainDict);

        NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
        id object = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:respData options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];

        if (jsonParsingError)
        {
            NSLog(@"JSON ERROR: %@", [jsonParsingError localizedDescription]);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"OBJECT: %@", [object class]);
        }

    }
```

Hope it helps you...!

Comment: … and what is it for?
`NSDictionary *dict;

            NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:NULL];
            [body appendData:jsonData];`

Comment: I assume I will get response in a Dictionary..So I wrote like that. Change the code as per your requirement..
Did you get anything at NSLog of @@@@@@@@@Data is..

Comment: I solved it. The problem was trivial - I had `multipart/form-data` set for `enctype` insted of `Content-Type`

Comment: Thanks Good. You can use my code also for uploading image. It will work..Accept my answer if it is helpful or related to your question..